# how to change dots with SVG in Particleground

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/vc-particleground-for-prestashop/full_screen_preview/13922144

Please check link and download all code as needed and let me know is it possible to change dot with custom SVG images file or some other icons

```js
/*!
 * Particleground
 *
 * @author Jonathan Nicol - @mrjnicol
 * @version 1.1.0
 * @description Creates a canvas based particle system background
 *
 * Inspired by http://requestlab.fr/ and http://disruptivebydesign.com/
 */
! function(t, e) {
    "use strict";

    function i(t) {
        t = t || {};
        for (var e = 1; e < arguments.length; e++) {
            var i = arguments[e];
            if (i)
                for (var a in i) i.hasOwnProperty(a) && ("object" == typeof i[a] ? deepExtend(t[a], i[a]) : t[a] = i[a])
        }
        return t
    }

    function a(a, n) {
        function r() {
            if (S) {
                y = e.createElement("canvas"), y.className = "pg-canvas", y.style.display = "block", a.insertBefore(y, a.firstChild), g = y.getContext("2d"), h();
                for (var i = Math.round(y.width * y.height / n.density), s = 0; i > s; s++) {
                    var o = new x;
                    o.setStackPos(s), b.push(o)
                }
                t.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                    l()
                }, !1), e.addEventListener("mousemove", function(t) {
                    w = t.pageX, P = t.pageY
                }, !1), T && !k && t.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function() {
                    F = Math.min(Math.max(-event.beta, -30), 30), C = Math.min(Math.max(-event.gamma, -30), 30)
                }, !0), p(), m("onInit")
            }
        }

        function h() {
            y.width = a.offsetWidth, y.height = a.offsetHeight, g.fillStyle = n.dotColor, g.strokeStyle = n.lineColor, g.lineWidth = n.lineWidth
        }

        function p() {
            if (S) {
                X = t.innerWidth, Y = t.innerHeight, g.clearRect(0, 0, y.width, y.height);
                for (var e = 0; e < b.length; e++) b[e].updatePosition();
                for (var e = 0; e < b.length; e++) b[e].draw();
                H || (v = requestAnimationFrame(p))
            }
        }

        function l() {
            h();
            for (var t = a.offsetWidth, e = a.offsetHeight, i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)(b[i].position.x > t || b[i].position.y > e) && b.splice(i, 1);
            var s = Math.round(y.width * y.height / n.density);
            if (s > b.length)
                for (; s > b.length;) {
                    var o = new x;
                    b.push(o)
                } else s < b.length && b.splice(s);
            for (i = b.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) b[i].setStackPos(i)
        }

        function f() {
            H = !0
        }

        function d() {
            H = !1, p()
        }

        function x() {
            switch (this.stackPos, this.active = !0, this.layer = Math.ceil(3 * Math.random()), this.parallaxOffsetX = 0, this.parallaxOffsetY = 0, this.position = {
                x: Math.ceil(Math.random() * y.width),
                y: Math.ceil(Math.random() * y.height)
            }, this.speed = {}, n.directionX) {
                case "left":
                    this.speed.x = +(-n.maxSpeedX + Math.random() * n.maxSpeedX - n.minSpeedX).toFixed(2);
                    break;
                case "right":
                    this.speed.x = +(Math.random() * n.maxSpeedX + n.minSpeedX).toFixed(2);
                    break;
                default:
                    this.speed.x = +(-n.maxSpeedX / 2 + Math.random() * n.maxSpeedX).toFixed(2), this.speed.x += this.speed.x > 0 ? n.minSpeedX : -n.minSpeedX
            }
            switch (n.directionY) {
                case "up":
                    this.speed.y = +(-n.maxSpeedY + Math.random() * n.maxSpeedY - n.minSpeedY).toFixed(2);
                    break;
                case "down":
                    this.speed.y = +(Math.random() * n.maxSpeedY + n.minSpeedY).toFixed(2);
                    break;
                default:
                    this.speed.y = +(-n.maxSpeedY / 2 + Math.random() * n.maxSpeedY).toFixed(2), this.speed.x += this.speed.y > 0 ? n.minSpeedY : -n.minSpeedY
            }
        }

        function c(t, e) {
            return e ? void(n[t] = e) : n[t]
        }

        function u() {
            console.log("destroy"), y.parentNode.removeChild(y), m("onDestroy"), o && o(a).removeData("plugin_" + s)
        }

        function m(t) {
            void 0 !== n[t] && n[t].call(a)
        }
        var y, g, v, X, Y, O, M, S = !!e.createElement("canvas").getContext,
            b = [],
            w = 0,
            P = 0,
            k = !navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|BB10|mobi|tablet|opera mini|nexus 7)/i),
            T = !!t.DeviceOrientationEvent,
            C = 0,
            F = 0,
            H = !1;
        return n = i({}, t[s].defaults, n), x.prototype.draw = function() {
            g.beginPath(), g.arc(this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY, n.particleRadius / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !0), g.closePath(), g.fill(), g.beginPath();
            for (var t = b.length - 1; t > this.stackPos; t--) {
                var e = b[t],
                    i = this.position.x - e.position.x,
                    s = this.position.y - e.position.y,
                    o = Math.sqrt(i * i + s * s).toFixed(2);
                o < n.proximity && (g.moveTo(this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY), n.curvedLines ? g.quadraticCurveTo(Math.max(e.position.x, e.position.x), Math.min(e.position.y, e.position.y), e.position.x + e.parallaxOffsetX, e.position.y + e.parallaxOffsetY) : g.lineTo(e.position.x + e.parallaxOffsetX, e.position.y + e.parallaxOffsetY))
            }
            var r = !1;
            if (n.grabHover) {
                var i = O - a.offsetLeft - this.position.x,
                    s = M - a.offsetTop - this.position.y,
                    o = Math.sqrt(i * i + s * s).toFixed(2);
                o < n.grabDistance && (r = !0, g.moveTo(this.position.x + this.parallaxOffsetX, this.position.y + this.parallaxOffsetY), g.lineTo(O - a.offsetLeft, M - a.offsetTop))
            }
            g.stroke(), g.closePath(), n.grabHover && r && (g.beginPath(), g.arc(O - a.offsetLeft, M - a.offsetTop, n.particleRadius / 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !0), g.closePath()), g.fill()
        }, x.prototype.updatePosition = function() {
            if (n.parallax) {
                if (T && !k) {
                    var t = (X - 0) / 60;
                    O = (C - -30) * t + 0;
                    var e = (Y - 0) / 60;
                    M = (F - -30) * e + 0
                } else O = w, M = P;
                this.parallaxTargX = (O - X / 2) / (n.parallaxMultiplier * this.layer), this.parallaxOffsetX += (this.parallaxTargX - this.parallaxOffsetX) / 10, this.parallaxTargY = (M - Y / 2) / (n.parallaxMultiplier * this.layer), this.parallaxOffsetY += (this.parallaxTargY - this.parallaxOffsetY) / 10
            } else n.grabHover && (O = w, M = P);
            var i = a.offsetWidth,
                s = a.offsetHeight;
            switch (n.directionX) {
                case "left":
                    this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX < 0 && (this.position.x = i - this.parallaxOffsetX);
                    break;
                case "right":
                    this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX > i && (this.position.x = 0 - this.parallaxOffsetX);
                    break;
                default:
                    (this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX > i || this.position.x + this.speed.x + this.parallaxOffsetX < 0) && (this.speed.x = -this.speed.x)
            }
            switch (n.directionY) {
                case "up":
                    this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY < 0 && (this.position.y = s - this.parallaxOffsetY);
                    break;
                case "down":
                    this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY > s && (this.position.y = 0 - this.parallaxOffsetY);
                    break;
                default:
                    (this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY > s || this.position.y + this.speed.y + this.parallaxOffsetY < 0) && (this.speed.y = -this.speed.y)
            }
            this.position.x += this.speed.x, this.position.y += this.speed.y
        }, x.prototype.setStackPos = function(t) {
            this.stackPos = t
        }, r(), {
            option: c,
            destroy: u,
            start: d,
            pause: f
        }
    }
    var s = "particleground",
        o = t.jQuery;
    t[s] = function(t, e) {
        return new a(t, e)
    }, t[s].defaults = {
        minSpeedX: .1,
        maxSpeedX: .7,
        minSpeedY: .1,
        maxSpeedY: .7,
        directionX: "center",
        directionY: "center",
        density: 1e4,
        dotColor: "#666666",
        lineColor: "#666666",
        particleRadius: 7,
        lineWidth: 1,
        curvedLines: !1,
        proximity: 100,
        parallax: !0,
        parallaxMultiplier: 5,
        grabHover: !0,
        grabDistance: 100,
        onInit: function() {},
        onDestroy: function() {}
    }, o && (o.fn[s] = function(t) {
        if ("string" == typeof arguments[0]) {
            var e, i = arguments[0],
                n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            return this.each(function() {
                o.data(this, "plugin_" + s) && "function" == typeof o.data(this, "plugin_" + s)[i] && (e = o.data(this, "plugin_" + s)[i].apply(this, n))
            }), void 0 !== e ? e : this
        }
        return "object" != typeof t && t ? void 0 : this.each(function() {
            o.data(this, "plugin_" + s) || o.data(this, "plugin_" + s, new a(this, t))
        })
    })
}(window, document),
/**
 * requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel
 * @see: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
 * @see: http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating
 * @license: MIT license
 */
function() {
    for (var a = 0, b = ["ms", "moz", "webkit", "o"], c = 0; c < b.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++c) window.requestAnimationFrame = window[b[c] + "RequestAnimationFrame"], window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[b[c] + "CancelAnimationFrame"] || window[b[c] + "CancelRequestAnimationFrame"];
    window.requestAnimationFrame || (window.requestAnimationFrame = function(b) {
        var c = (new Date).getTime(),
            d = Math.max(0, 16 - (c - a)),
            e = window.setTimeout(function() {
                b(c + d)
            }, d);
        return a = c + d, e
    }), window.cancelAnimationFrame || (window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(a) {
        clearTimeout(a)
    })
}();





/**
 * Particleground demo
 * @author Jonathan Nicol - @mrjnicol
 */
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Full
    var selector = $('#intro_particle');
        
    var bgColor = selector.data('bgcolor');
    var minSpeedX = selector.data('minspeedx');
    var maxSpeedX = selector.data('maxspeedx');
    var minSpeedY = selector.data('minspeedy');
    var maxSpeedY = selector.data('maxspeedy');
    var directionX = selector.data('directionx');
    var directionY = selector.data('directiony');
    var density = selector.data('density');
    var dotColor = selector.data('dotcolor');
    var lineColor = selector.data('linecolor');
    var particleRadius = selector.data('particleradius');
    var lineWidth = selector.data('linewidth');
    var proximity = selector.data('proximity');
    var parallax = selector.data('parallax');
    var parallaxMultiplier = selector.data('parallaxmultiplier');
    var grabHover = selector.data('grabhover');
    var grabDistance = selector.data('grabdistance');
    
    selector.particleground({
        minSpeedX: minSpeedX/10,
        maxSpeedX: maxSpeedX/10,
        minSpeedY: minSpeedY/10,
        maxSpeedY: maxSpeedY/10,
        directionX: directionX,
        directionY: directionY,
        density: density,
        dotColor: dotColor,
        lineColor: lineColor,
        particleRadius: particleRadius,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        proximity: proximity,
        parallax: parallax,
        parallaxMultiplier: parallaxMultiplier, 
        grabHover: grabHover,
        grabDistance: grabDistance
    });
    
    $('#intro').css({
        'margin-top': -($('#intro_particle').height() / 2 + $('#intro').height() / 2)
    });
    
    // Feature
    selector = $('#feature_particle');
        
    bgColor = selector.data('bgcolor');
    minSpeedX = selector.data('minspeedx');
    maxSpeedX = selector.data('maxspeedx');
    minSpeedY = selector.data('minspeedy');
    maxSpeedY = selector.data('maxspeedy');
    directionX = selector.data('directionx');
    directionY = selector.data('directiony');
    density = selector.data('density');
    dotColor = selector.data('dotcolor');
    lineColor = selector.data('linecolor');
    particleRadius = selector.data('particleradius');
    lineWidth = selector.data('linewidth');
    proximity = selector.data('proximity');
    parallax = selector.data('parallax');
    parallaxMultiplier = selector.data('parallaxmultiplier');
    grabHover = selector.data('grabhover');
    grabDistance = selector.data('grabdistance');
    
    selector.particleground({
        minSpeedX: minSpeedX/10,
        maxSpeedX: maxSpeedX/10,
        minSpeedY: minSpeedY/10,
        maxSpeedY: maxSpeedY/10,
        directionX: directionX,
        directionY: directionY,
        density: density,
        dotColor: dotColor,
        lineColor: lineColor,
        particleRadius: particleRadius,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        proximity: proximity,
        parallax: parallax,
        parallaxMultiplier: parallaxMultiplier, 
        grabHover: grabHover,
        grabDistance: grabDistance
    });
    
    $('#feature').css({
        'margin-top': -($('#feature_particle').height() / 2 + $('#feature').height() / 2)
    });
    
    // Custom
    selector = $('#custom_particle');
        
    bgColor = selector.data('bgcolor');
    minSpeedX = selector.data('minspeedx');
    maxSpeedX = selector.data('maxspeedx');
    minSpeedY = selector.data('minspeedy');
    maxSpeedY = selector.data('maxspeedy');
    directionX = selector.data('directionx');
    directionY = selector.data('directiony');
    density = selector.data('density');
    dotColor = selector.data('dotcolor');
    lineColor = selector.data('linecolor');
    particleRadius = selector.data('particleradius');
    lineWidth = selector.data('linewidth');
    proximity = selector.data('proximity');
    parallax = selector.data('parallax');
    parallaxMultiplier = selector.data('parallaxmultiplier');
    grabHover = selector.data('grabhover');
    grabDistance = selector.data('grabdistance');
    
    selector.particleground({
        minSpeedX: minSpeedX/10,
        maxSpeedX: maxSpeedX/10,
        minSpeedY: minSpeedY/10,
        maxSpeedY: maxSpeedY/10,
        directionX: directionX,
        directionY: directionY,
        density: density,
        dotColor: dotColor,
        lineColor: lineColor,
        particleRadius: particleRadius,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        proximity: proximity,
        parallax: parallax,
        parallaxMultiplier: parallaxMultiplier, 
        grabHover: grabHover,
        grabDistance: grabDistance
    });
    
    $('#custom').css({
        'margin-top': -($('#custom_particle').height() / 2 + $('#custom').height() / 2)
    });
    
    // Custom color
    selector = $('#custom_color_particle');
        
    bgColor = selector.data('bgcolor');
    minSpeedX = selector.data('minspeedx');
    maxSpeedX = selector.data('maxspeedx');
    minSpeedY = selector.data('minspeedy');
    maxSpeedY = selector.data('maxspeedy');
    directionX = selector.data('directionx');
    directionY = selector.data('directiony');
    density = selector.data('density');
    dotColor = selector.data('dotcolor');
    lineColor = selector.data('linecolor');
    particleRadius = selector.data('particleradius');
    lineWidth = selector.data('linewidth');
    proximity = selector.data('proximity');
    parallax = selector.data('parallax');
    parallaxMultiplier = selector.data('parallaxmultiplier');
    grabHover = selector.data('grabhover');
    grabDistance = selector.data('grabdistance');
    
    selector.particleground({
        minSpeedX: minSpeedX/10,
        maxSpeedX: maxSpeedX/10,
        minSpeedY: minSpeedY/10,
        maxSpeedY: maxSpeedY/10,
        directionX: directionX,
        directionY: directionY,
        density: density,
        dotColor: dotColor,
        lineColor: lineColor,
        particleRadius: particleRadius,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        proximity: proximity,
        parallax: parallax,
        parallaxMultiplier: parallaxMultiplier, 
        grabHover: grabHover,
        grabDistance: grabDistance
    });
    
    $('#custom_color').css({
        'margin-top': -($('#custom_color_particle').height() / 2 + $('#custom_color').height() / 2)
    });
    
    // Custom proximity
    selector = $('#custom_proximity_particle');
        
    bgColor = selector.data('bgcolor');
    minSpeedX = selector.data('minspeedx');
    maxSpeedX = selector.data('maxspeedx');
    minSpeedY = selector.data('minspeedy');
    maxSpeedY = selector.data('maxspeedy');
    directionX = selector.data('directionx');
    directionY = selector.data('directiony');
    density = selector.data('density');
    dotColor = selector.data('dotcolor');
    lineColor = selector.data('linecolor');
    particleRadius = selector.data('particleradius');
    lineWidth = selector.data('linewidth');
    proximity = selector.data('proximity');
    parallax = selector.data('parallax');
    parallaxMultiplier = selector.data('parallaxmultiplier');
    grabHover = selector.data('grabhover');
    grabDistance = selector.data('grabdistance');
    
    selector.particleground({
        minSpeedX: minSpeedX/10,
        maxSpeedX: maxSpeedX/10,
        minSpeedY: minSpeedY/10,
        maxSpeedY: maxSpeedY/10,
        directionX: directionX,
        directionY: directionY,
        density: density,
        dotColor: dotColor,
        lineColor: lineColor,
        particleRadius: particleRadius,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        proximity: proximity,
        parallax: parallax,
        parallaxMultiplier: parallaxMultiplier, 
        grabHover: grabHover,
        grabDistance: grabDistance
    });
    
    $('#custom_proximity').css({
        'margin-top': -($('#custom_proximity_particle').height() / 2 + $('#custom_proximity').height() / 2)
    });
    
    // Custom parallax
    selector = $('#custom_parallax_particle');
        
    bgColor = selector.data('bgcolor');
    minSpeedX = selector.data('minspeedx');
    maxSpeedX = selector.data('maxspeedx');
    minSpeedY = selector.data('minspeedy');
    maxSpeedY = selector.data('maxspeedy');
    directionX = selector.data('directionx');
    directionY = selector.data('directiony');
    density = selector.data('density');
    dotColor = selector.data('dotcolor');
    lineColor = selector.data('linecolor');
    particleRadius = selector.data('particleradius');
    lineWidth = selector.data('linewidth');
    proximity = selector.data('proximity');
    parallax = selector.data('parallax');
    parallaxMultiplier = selector.data('parallaxmultiplier');
    grabHover = selector.data('grabhover');
    grabDistance = selector.data('grabdistance');
    
    selector.particleground({
        minSpeedX: minSpeedX/10,
        maxSpeedX: maxSpeedX/10,
        minSpeedY: minSpeedY/10,
        maxSpeedY: maxSpeedY/10,
        directionX: directionX,
        directionY: directionY,
        density: density,
        dotColor: dotColor,
        lineColor: lineColor,
        particleRadius: particleRadius,
        lineWidth: lineWidth,
        proximity: proximity,
        parallax: parallax,
        parallaxMultiplier: parallaxMultiplier, 
        grabHover: grabHover,
        grabDistance: grabDistance
    });
    
    $('#custom_parallax').css({
        'margin-top': -($('#custom_parallax_particle').height() / 2 + $('#custom_parallax').height() / 2)
    });
});
```

```css
.contain-to-grid{
    background: #5cbdaa;
}
.top-bar{
    background: none;
}
.top-bar .name h1 a {
    color: #FFF;
}

.top-bar-section ul li, .top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button){
    background: none;
}
.top-bar-section ul, .top-bar-section a:not(.button){
    background: none;
}

.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:hover:not(.button){
    background: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #005544;
    
}
.top-bar-section a:hover:not(.button){
    background: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #005544;    
}

.top-bar-section ul li > a{
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.top-bar-section ul > a{
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0 8px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 position:relative;
}

.active{
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

.row:before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -90px; 
  height: 90px; 
  visibility: hidden;
    
}

section{
}

.envato{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.copyright{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.copyright p{
    color: #0E0684;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.copyright a{
    color: #0E0684;
}

ul, ol, dl {
    list-style: none;
}

.th{
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 150px;
}

#intro {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;    
}

#intro_particle {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#custom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;    
}

#custom_particle {
    background: #B17111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#custom_color {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;    
}

#custom_color_particle {
    background: #B17111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#custom_proximity {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;    
}

#custom_proximity_particle {
    background: #B17111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#custom_parallax {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;    
}

#custom_parallax_particle {
    background: #B17111;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#feature {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;    
}

#feature_particle {
    background: #110B63;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#envato {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.f-topbar-fixed{
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
.social a{
    padding: 0 5px !important;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

button, .button{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.015em;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
     -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
       -o-transition: all 0.4s;
          transition: all 0.4s;
}

button:hover, .button:hover{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #005544;
    border-color: #005544;
}
h1, h2, h3, h5, h6 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
}
a, p {
    color: #FFF;
}
a:hover{
    color: #000;
}

.top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a span:after {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FFF, 0 7px 0 1px #FFF, 0 14px 0 1px #FFF;
}

.top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
    padding: 0 30px 0 15px;
    
}
.top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon {
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro_particle" data-bgColor="#000" data-minSpeedX="10" data-maxSpeedX="10" data-minSpeedY="10"  data-maxSpeedY="10" data-directionX="center" data-directionY="center" data-density="10000" data-dotColor="#000" data-lineColor="#000" data-particleRadius="7" data-lineWidth="1" data-proximity="100" data-parallax="false" data-parallaxMultiplier="5" data-grabHover="true" data-grabDistance="200"></div>
```

Comment: _"Please check link and download all code"_ Nobody is going to go to that much effort. Make life easy for the people that you want to help you. Post relevant code here.

Comment: Let me check  if i can upload all code

Comment: _"relevant code"_

Comment: Please check now